# Order queryset by alternating value

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
    client = models.Charfield(max_length=255)
```

`client` is the name of the client as could have values like `facebook`, `google`, and so on.

Is it possible to order the queryset so that the result is alternating the values of `client`?
What I expect is something like this:

```
Entry.objects.order_by('alternate client') --> 

| client   | name   |
| google   | robert |
| facebook | linda  |
| google   | kate   | 
| facebook | jack   |
| google   | nina   |
| facebook | pierre |
```

I am using django2.x and postgres if that helps.

EDIT:

Some additional info / requirements.

- I have about 10 to 20 differtent clients
- Entry does also have a `created` DateField. If possible result should also be ordered by date
- I want to use pagination for Entry so solution should be using django's ORM

Comment: Any particular order requirements for the `name` column? Can they be in any order?

Comment: Yes, they can be in any order. 
In the real example I have a `created` field. Would be great if that can be ordered descending.

Comment: What is that `alternate`? Do you need just `Entry.objects.order_by('client').order_by('-name')?

Comment: No, what I need that in the result `client` is alterating. for two values like this: facebook, google, facebook, google, ...

Comment: How many `clients` do u have?

Comment: something in the range 10 to 20

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you use Postgres you can use its [Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) which perform a calculation across a set of table rows that are somehow related to the current row. Another good information relies in the fact that you use Django2.x which supports Window Functions([Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#window-functions)) which allows adding an `OVER` clause to `Querysets`.

Your use-case can be resolved with Single ORM query like:

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Window
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber
from django.db.models import F

results = Entry.objects.annotate(row_number=Window(
    expression=RowNumber(),
    partition_by=[F('client')],
    order_by=F('created').desc())
).order_by('row_number', 'client')

for result in results:
    print('Id: {} - client: {} - row_number {}'.format(result.id, result.client, result.row_number))
```

Output:

```
Id: 12 - client: facebook - row_number 1
Id: 13 - client: google - row_number 1
Id: 11 - client: facebook - row_number 2
Id: 8 - client: google - row_number 2
Id: 10 - client: facebook - row_number 3
Id: 5 - client: google - row_number 3
Id: 9 - client: facebook - row_number 4
Id: 3 - client: google - row_number 4
Id: 7 - client: facebook - row_number 5
Id: 2 - client: google - row_number 5
Id: 6 - client: facebook - row_number 6
Id: 1 - client: google - row_number 6
Id: 4 - client: facebook - row_number 7
```

The raw SQL looks like:

```
SELECT 
"orm_entry"."id",
"orm_entry"."name",
"orm_entry"."client",
"orm_entry"."created",
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "orm_entry"."client" ORDER BY "orm_entry"."created" DESC) AS "row_number" 
FROM "orm_entry" 
ORDER BY "row_number" ASC, "orm_entry"."client" ASC
```

Window functions are declared just as an aggregate function followed by an OVER clause, which indicates exactly how rows are being grouped. The group of rows onto which the window function is applied is called "partition".

You can notice that we grouped the rows by **'client'** field and you can conclude that in our example we will have the two partitions. First partition will contain all the '**facebook'** entries and second partition will contain all the **'google'** entries. In its basic form, a partition is no different than a normal aggregate function group: simply a set of rows considered "equal" by some criteria, and the function will be applied over all these rows to return a single result.

In your example we can use the [`row_number`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) window function which simply returns the index of the current row within its partition starting from 1. That helped me to establish the alternating output in `order_by('row_number', 'client')`.

***Additional information:***

If you want to achieve an order like this:

`'facebook','facebook', 'google','google','facebook','facebook','google','google'`

or

`'facebook','facebook','facebook','google','google','google','facebook', 'facebook','facebook'`

You will need to do one small math related modification of the previous query like:

```
GROUP_SIZE = 2
results = Entry.objects.annotate(row_number=Window(
    expression=RowNumber(),
    partition_by=[F('client')],
    order_by=F('created').desc())
).annotate(row_number=(F('row_number') - 1)/GROUP_SIZE + 1).order_by('row_number', 'client')

for result in results:
    print('Id: {} - client: {} - row_number {}'.format(result.id, result.client, result.row_number))
```

Output:

```
Id: 12 - client: facebook - row_number 1
Id: 11 - client: facebook - row_number 1
Id: 8 - client: google - row_number 1
Id: 13 - client: google - row_number 1
Id: 10 - client: facebook - row_number 2
Id: 9 - client: facebook - row_number 2
Id: 3 - client: google - row_number 2
Id: 5 - client: google - row_number 2
Id: 7 - client: facebook - row_number 3
Id: 6 - client: facebook - row_number 3
Id: 1 - client: google - row_number 3
Id: 2 - client: google - row_number 3
Id: 4 - client: facebook - row_number 4
```

You can notice that `GROUP_SIZE` constant defines how many items will be in the each alternating group.

**P.S.**

Thank you for asking this question because it helped me to better understand the Window Functions.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Very nice! Thank you, that's exatctly what I was looking for. I have one additional question. Is it also possible with this approach to get an order like this: "facebook, facebook, google, google, facebook, facebook, google, google"

Comment: You're welcome. It is possible but it requires some small modifications of the ORM query. I updated my answer so feel free to take a look at the 'Additional information' paragraph.

Comment: This is a great answer not only for Django users! Thank you.

Comment: this answer is great & should be the accepted answer! +1

Answer (score 3):

Thats not the most performant way, but works:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from django.db.models import Case, When

grouped_pks = []
for client in Entry.objects.values_list('client', flat=True).distinct():
    grouped_pks.append(
        Entry.objects.filter(client=client).values_list('pk', flat=True)
    )

alternated_pks = [
    x for x in
    filter(
        None,
        sum(zip_longest(*grouped_pks), ())
    )
]
alternated_pks_order = Case(
    *[
        When(pk=pk, then=position)
        for position, pk in enumerate(alternated_pks)
    ]
)

entries = Entry.objects.filter(pk__in=alternated_pks).order_by(alternated_pks_order)
for entry in entries:
    print('id: {} - client: {}'.format(entry.id, entry.client))
```

Expected output:

```
id: 8901 - client: google
id: 8890 - client: facebook
id: 8884 - client: google
id: 8894 - client: facebook
id: 8748 - client: google
id: 8891 - client: facebook
id: 8906 - client: google
id: 8909 - client: facebook
id: 8888 - client: google
id: 8895 - client: facebook
id: 8919 - client: google
id: 8910 - client: facebook
id: 8878 - client: google
id: 8896 - client: facebook
id: 8916 - client: google
id: 8902 - client: facebook
id: 8917 - client: google
id: 8885 - client: facebook
id: 8918 - client: google
id: 8903 - client: facebook
id: 8920 - client: google
id: 8886 - client: facebook
id: 8904 - client: facebook
id: 8905 - client: facebook
id: 8887 - client: facebook
id: 8911 - client: facebook
id: 8897 - client: facebook
id: 8912 - client: facebook
id: 8898 - client: facebook
id: 8899 - client: facebook
id: 8914 - client: facebook
id: 8900 - client: facebook
id: 8915 - client: facebook
```

This is python3 code, but if you want to use it with python 2, change the `zip_longest` function to `izip_longest`.

This code is nice, because we still work with Queryset, so all other Sorting, Ordering, Managers, Pagination and other stuff will still work.

Comment: Thanks! Would this also work for an unknown number of clients?

Comment: Hi @ilse2005, i just updated the answer to support it. The logic is the same as before, but instead of passing one by one on `zip_longest ` we create a list of lists and using the unpack `*` sign to pass the params.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will work, with numpy module

```
import numpy
queryset = Entry.objects.all()

''' catch the number of distinct Entry considering the client fields '''

queryset_client_entries = Entry.objects.distinct('client')

new_list = list(numpy.resize(queryset_client_entries, queryset.count())) 
''' An alternative list of clients depending on the length of queryset '''
```

Comment: Not sure if I get your answer.
Also would be great to do it with django's ORM because I want use pagination later on and the list of entries can be quite long.