# How to limit no. of consecutive objects with a certain property in django queryset?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    department = models.ForeignKey("Department", ...)
    ......
    ...
```

Here's a queryset that returns best performing employees in a company sorted over the annotated field **`score`**.

```
best = Employees.objects.filter(...some filters).annotate(score=...some calculations).order_by('-score')
```

How to limit the queryset to return a maximum of **`2 or n`** no. of consecutive employees with same department?

**current result:**(only printing department for time sake)

```
dep5, dep9, dep9, dep9, dep9, dep5, dep5, dep4, dep4, dep4
```

**Expected result:**(only printing department for time sake)

```
dep5, dep9, dep9, dep5, dep5, dep4, dep4
```

**Note**:

I have done my research, and not able to find any solution. Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120467/order-queryset-by-alternating-value use ROW_NUMBER with `partition_by=department_id`, annotate it with e.g. `rn` and filter like `rn <= 2`

Comment: @IvanStarostin It's throwing Window clause cannot be used with filter. `q.annotate(row_number=Window(expression=RowNumber(), partition_by=[F('department')])).filter(row_number__lte=2).order_by('row_number', '-score')`