# How to annotate a QuerySet adding row numbers groupped by a field?

Tags: django, orm

I have two models:

Model **books** [id, title, author_id]

Model **authors** [id, name]

I need to query books ordered by author name and title:

```py
result = Books.order_by('author__name', 'title').value_list('author__name', 'title')
```

But I also need to add a counter to each row which will reset with each new author.

The results of the query should be:

```
title      name                  position
-----------------------------------------
book1      Dan Brown             1
book2      Douglas Adams         1
book3      Douglas Adams         2
book4      Douglas Adams         3
book5      Douglas Adams         4
book6      Ernest Hemingway      1
book7      Ernest Hemingway      2
book8      Ernest Hemingway      3
book9      John Steinbeck        1
book10     John Steinbeck        2
```

Is it possible to implement this `position` field with Django ORM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120467/order-queryset-by-alternating-value)

In you case, I think this should work

```
from django.db.models.expressions import Window
from django.db.models.functions import RowNumber
from django.db.models import F

result = (
    Books.order_by("author__name", "title")
    .annotate(
        row_number=Window(
            expression=RowNumber(), partition_by=[F("author")], order_by=[F("title")]
        )
    )
    .value_list("author__name", "title", "row_number")
)
```